# How to export a mxGraph to a visio diagram?

Tags: java, visio, jgraph, mxgraph

I've implemented a graph using mxGraph libraries. Is there any way to export this graph to visio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do it by youself.Here is the step：

1. Encode the graph to xml.
2. Trans the xml to your own object.
3. Draw it.

Answer (score 2):

mxGraph doesn't support that functionality. [draw.io](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio) does have export to .vsdx, however.